# problem with eclipse Galileo version

Tags: eclipse, ejb-3.1

for adding jars, when i select Deployment assembly-add-java build path entries...i have nothing ....no jars are there to select....what should i do?Please send me the ans.

Answer (score 0):

Building WAR/EAR's uses a *different* mechanism from the Java Build Path.   You will need to include jar files specifically in this list to have it included in the generated file.